# split large regular expression in different lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this regular expression:

```
INVALID_NAMES = /\b(bib$|costumes$|httpanties?|necklace|cuff link|cufflink|scarf|pendant|apron|buckle|beanie|hat|ring|blanket|polo|earrings?|plush|pacifier|tie$|panties|boxers?|slippers?|pants?|leggings|ibattz|dress|bodysuits?|charm|battstation|tea|pocket ref|pajamas?|boyshorts?|mimopowertube|coat|bathrobe)\b/i
```

and it's working in that way.... but I want to write something like this:

```
INVALID_NAMES = /\b(bib$|costumes$|httpanties?|necklace|cuff link|
                    cufflink|scarf|pendant|apron|buckle|beanie|hat|ring|blanket|
                    polo|earrings?|plush|pacifier|tie$|panties|boxers?|
                    slippers?|pants?|leggings|ibattz|dress|bodysuits?|charm|
                    battstation|tea|pocket ref|pajamas?|boyshorts?|
                    mimopowertube|coat|bathrobe)\b/i
```

but if I use the second option the words: cufflink, polo, slippers?, battstation and mimopowertube.... are not taken because the spaces that the word have before, example:

```
(this space before the word)cufflink
```

I'll be very grateful of any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Construct Your Regex with the Space-Insensitive Flag

You can use the [space-insensitive flag](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Options) to ignore whitespace and comments in your regular expression. Note that you will need to use `\s` or other explicit characters to catch whitespace once you enable this flag, since the `/x` flag would otherwise cause the spaces to be ignored.

Consider the following example:

```
INVALID_NAMES =
    /\b(bib$          |
        costumes$     |
        httpanties?   |
        necklace      |
        cuff\slink    |
        cufflink      |
        scarf         |
        pendant       |
        apron         |
        buckle        |
        beanie        |
        hat           |
        ring          |
        blanket       |
        polo          |
        earrings?     |
        plush         |
        pacifier      |
        tie$          |
        panties       |
        boxers?       |
        slippers?     |
        pants?        |
        leggings      |
        ibattz        |
        dress         |
        bodysuits?    |
        charm         |
        battstation   |
        tea           |
        pocket\sref   |
        pajamas?      |
        boyshorts?    |
        mimopowertube |
        coat          |
        bathrobe
    )\b/ix
```

Note that you can format it in many other ways, but having one expression per line makes it easier to sort and edit your sub-expressions. If you want it to have multiple alternatives per line, you could certainly do that.

### Making Sure It Works

You can see that the expression above works as intended with the following examples:

```
'cufflink'.match INVALID_NAMES
#=> #<MatchData "cufflink" 1:"cufflink">

'cuff link'.match INVALID_NAMES
#=> #<MatchData "cuff link" 1:"cuff link">
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution that you give me. I marked as correct because is the most "regexp" approach between the solutions presented here.

Comment: There's a problem with `bib$`, because of `$`: `'bib$'.match INVALID_NAMES #=> nil`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland It works fine for me: `'bib'.match INVALID_NAMES #=> #<MatchData "bib" 1:"bib">`. YMMV.

Comment: Am I missing something? Are `?` and `$` intended to have some special significance, or are they just characters? My point is that if `'bib$'` (not `'bib'`) is among the 'invalid words' and a string contains `'bib$'` (not `'bib'`), it won't be caught.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `$` is end-of-line. `?` is zero-or-one. Unless escaped, they are atoms, not characters. Basic regular expression stuff. The question is not about whether the OP's regular expressions will match a given corpus, but about spacing and line wraps, so you're *way* overthinking this.

Comment: Yes, of course! I was confused between words and the regexes to find them. Not the OP's fault--it's very clear. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 3):

You may use something like this

```
INVALID_NAMES = [
  "bib$",
  "costumes$",
  "httpanties?",
  "necklace"
]
INVALID_NAMES_REGEX = /\b(#{INVALID_NAMES.join '|'})\b/i
p INVALID_NAMES_REGEX
```

Comment: I really like your approach :D but I did: INVALID_NAMES = /\b(#{["word1", "word2", "etc"].join('|')})\b/i    thanks man!

Comment: @CarySwoveland the thing is that "bib$" its a string and when you try to apply "bib$"[INVALID_NAMES_REGEX] is not gonna work because "bib$" is not inside (which is inside is "bib") INVALID_NAMES_REGEX. Also the symbol "$" is denoting only the final of the line in the regular expression as you can see here: http://rubular.com/

Comment: My apologies. I was mixed-up. See my comment to gnome's answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a newline in the middle of a regex literal, the newline becomes a part of the regular expression. Look at this example:

```
"ab" =~ /ab/ # => 0

"ab" =~ /a
b/ # => nil

"a\nb" =~ /a
b/ # => 0
```

You can suppress the newline by appending a backslash at the end of the line:

```
"ab" =~ /a\
b/ # => 0
```

Applied to your regex (leading spaces also removed):

```
INVALID_NAMES = /\b(bib$|costumes$|httpanties?|necklace|cuff link|\
cufflink|scarf|pendant|apron|buckle|beanie|hat|ring|blanket|\
polo|earrings?|plush|pacifier|tie$|panties|boxers?|\
slippers?|pants?|leggings|ibattz|dress|bodysuits?|charm|\
battstation|tea|pocket ref|pajamas?|boyshorts?|\
mimopowertube|coat|bathrobe)\b/i
```

Comment: yeah its a good approach but I really want to leave the indentation space, so I can't apply your solution. Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You might do it like this:

```
INVALID_NAMES = ['necklace', 'cuff link', 'cufflink', 'scarf', 'tie?', 'bib$']
r = Regexp.union(INVALID_NAMES.map { |n| /\b#{n}\b/i })

str = 'cat \n  cufflink bib cuff link. tie Scarf\n cow necklace? \n  ti. bib'
str.scan(r)
  #=> ["cufflink", "cuff link", "tie", "Scarf", "necklace", "ti", "bib"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your patterns are inefficient and will cause the Regexp engine to thrash badly.

I'd recommend you investigate what Perl's Regexp::Assemble can do to help your Ruby code:

- "[How do I ignore file types in a web crawler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888210/how-do-i-ignore-file-types-in-a-web-crawler/8891145#8891145)"
- "[Is there an efficient way to perform hundreds of text substitutions in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395236/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-perform-hundreds-of-text-substitutions-in-ruby/5395777#5395777)"