# And/Or operator is ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a quick question on Ruby syntax:
I am trying to write a program where it takes a string and replaces substrings with a different substring IF it contains the initial substring. Here is my code:

```
print "Thtring, pleathe!"

user_input = gets.chomp

if user_input.include? "s" || "S" || "cy" || "ce" || "ci"

    user_input.gsub!(/s/, "th")
    user_input.gsub!(/S/, "Th") 
    user_input.gsub!(/cy/, "th") 
    user_input.gsub!(/ce/, "th") 
    user_input.gsub!(/ci/, "th") 
else

    puts "No 's' found!"
end

puts "#{user_input}!"
```

This works fine until I have a sentence that doesn't contain "s" in it. Then it just prints the original string with no changes. Is there a logical operator that means AND/OR in Ruby? To replace all the ORs (`||`) with. And if there isn't, how would I rewrite this to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing now is effectively

```
if user_input.include?("s") || "S" || "cy" || "ce" || "ci"
```

(Note the added parentheses.) Also, you can't do something like that in Ruby - the `||` operator only works for boolean expressions.

You have two alternatives:

```
if user_input.include?("s") || user_input.include?("S") || user_input.include?("cy") || user_input.include?("ce") || user_input.include?("ci")
```

or the much neater

```
if user_input =~ /s|S|cy|ce|ci/
```

Comment: Or the shorter `/s|S|c[yei]/`

Answer (score 2):

It is just:

```
print "Thtring, pleathe!"
user_input = gets.chomp

puts "No 's' found!" unless user_input.gsub!(/s|S|cy|ce|ci/, 'th')

puts "#{user_input}!"
```

What works, because `gsub!` returns `nil` if nothing is replaced.

Answer (score 1):

There's some seemingly little-known magic that [`gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-gsub) can do using a regexp pattern and a hash.

Starting with a hash of the target strings to be found and their replacements:

```
substitutions = {
  's' => "th",
  'S' => "Th",
  'cy' => "th",
  'ce' => "th",
  'ci' => "th",
}
```

We can build a regular expression based on the keys (target strings):

```
substitution_pattern = Regexp.union(substitutions.keys) # => /s|S|cy|ce|ci/
```

And pass the pattern and the hash to `gsub`:

```
'String please!'.gsub(substitution_pattern, substitutions) # => "Thtring pleathe!"
```

Here are the individual tests:

```
's'.gsub(substitution_pattern, substitutions) # => "th"
'S'.gsub(substitution_pattern, substitutions) # => "Th"
'cy'.gsub(substitution_pattern, substitutions) # => "th"
'ce'.gsub(substitution_pattern, substitutions) # => "th"
'ci'.gsub(substitution_pattern, substitutions) # => "th"
```

The pattern being built by `Regexp.union` isn't especially good, because all it really does is `join('|')`. We can easily create a smarter pattern:

```
substitution_pattern = /[Ss]|c[eiy]/
'String please!'.gsub(substitution_pattern, substitutions) # => "Thtring pleathe!"
```

There are several answers on Stack Overflow where I use a Perl module called [Regexp::Assemble](http://search.cpan.org/~dland/Regexp-Assemble-0.35/Assemble.pm) to generate very complex patterns for this purpose. Check out these [Regexp::Assemble answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A128421+regexp%3A%3Aassemble) for more information. In particular, "[Is there an efficient way to perform hundreds of text substitutions in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395236/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-perform-hundreds-of-text-substitutions-in-ruby/5395777#5395777)" will show you all you need to know to do this.

Comment: This one is pretty golden. Though I second the little-known aspect here. I've personally never seen this one, although in retrospect and checking the docs you'd expect this to be more popular

Comment: This is getting into some of the deeper magic inside Ruby. I've found that a lot of developers tend to not want to dig into languages and are content with the surface stuff, but the real power of a language is not on the surface. With a proper set of keys, or a well constructed regex pattern, this can offload a huge amount of processing to the regex engine and lookups into a hash, both of which can be extremely fast.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way of doing it is to just use a regexp. You could do

```
if user_input.match(/(s|S|cy|ce|ci)/)
  ...
else
  ...
end
```

There are also, as always, other options such as in Milan Vladimirovic's answer:

```
if user_input =~ /(s|S|cy|ce|ci)/
```

as well as Tin Man's suggestion

```
if user_input[/(s|S|cy|ce|ci)/]
```

Use whichever you prefer since they are for this scenario functionally equivalent. The other thing is you could just run the `gsub`s anyway since they won't cahnge anything that isn't there, unless you really want to output the `"No 's' found!"`

Comment: Use `user_input[/s|S|c[yei]/]` instead.

Comment: Nice one! I'd actually forgotten you can do that one. Typically i go for the worded ones if they read nicely, though this one is quite clean and concise

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a problem with operator binding priorities. Wrapping the ORs (`||`) in brackets (`include?('s') || include?('S')`) should do the trick and make your code work.

You could also write it as a regular expression:

```
if user_input =~ /s|S|cy|ce|ci/
  user_input.gsub!(/s/, "th")
  user_input.gsub!(/S/, "Th") 
  user_input.gsub!(/cy/, "th") 
  user_input.gsub!(/ce/, "th") 
  user_input.gsub!(/ci/, "th")
else
  puts "No 's' found!"
end
```