# Match a huge list of keywords against a string using ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, performance

I have a lot of text documents on the one hand and a huge list of Keywords (Strings) on the other hand. Now I'm interested, which of these keywords are contained in the documents.

At the moment I'm using a monstrous auto generated regex:

```
keywords = %w(Key1, Key2, Key3)
regx = Regexp.new('\b(' + keywords.join('|') + ')\b','i')
documents.each |d|
    d.scan(regx)
end
```

This worked great for a List of a few hundred keywords but now I'm using about 50000 keywords and it's slowing down too much.

Is there a better way doing such an operation using ruby?

**EDIT:**

- The Documents are typical news articles like news about recent sport events as you can find via google news for example. In my testset each article contains about 1000 Words
- The Keywords can be single words but could also be phrases containing multiple words like 'Franz Beckenbauer' or 'Russel Wilson'.
- I'm interested only in complete matches - so searching for 'diction' should only match 'diction', not 'dictionary'

Comment: Use `StringScanner`.

Comment: Is the slowdown linear with respect to the number of keywords? If so, I don't think you can improve from that.

Comment: Do you only want whole words matched from the documents, and not partial strings?  Do you want a search for "diction" to return "dictionary"?

Comment: Roughly how many words are in each document?

Comment: You may wish to consider creating, for each document, a set of words contained in the document. You can then quickly determine if each key word is in the set.

Comment: Thinking the same thing --- using .to_set and then getting the intersection of the word set and file set

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395236/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-perform-hundreds-of-text-substitutions-in-ruby/5395777#5395777. Not all regular expressions are created alike, and using `Regexp.union` or concatenating strings using `|` won't necessarily create efficient patterns. Without a better idea of the words you're using, the regex being generated and the files you're scanning it's difficult to help with detailed answers. There are tricks to speed up regex, and poorly written regex can be very slow, much slower than a simple in-string search.

Comment: @JLB, after a bit more thought I doubt that creating a set of words in a file and then checking each keyword against that set is faster than the reverse, creating a set of keywords and then checking each word in each file against that set.

Comment: @theTinMan There's at least one gem that does something similar: [regexp_trie](https://github.com/gfx/ruby-regexp_trie). It looks like it's based on Perl's [Regexp::Trie](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Trie), which claims to be "a faster but simpler version of Regexp::Assemble or Regexp::Optimizer." It works pretty well—see my answer below.

Comment: Actually, scratch that (for now). I unfortunately came across [a pretty significant bug](https://github.com/gfx/ruby-regexp_trie/issues/1) in regexp_trie. If the bug gets fixed I'll undelete my answer.

Comment: Trie is a building block. Dig into the code of Regexp::Assemble and you'll see there's a lot more to it.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the list of keywords to a hash:

```
h = {
  "foo" => true,
  "bar" => true,
  ...
  "baz" => true,
}
```

Then, read the document chunk by chunk (separated by space):

```
File.new("/path/to/file").each(" ") do
  |ws| ws.scan(/[\w']+/) do
    |w| if h.key?(w)
      # Found.
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why a hash rather than a set?

Comment: A set is a hash in disguise with some icing.

Comment: @theTinMan, yes, but my question stands.

Comment: If I only want to know if a single element exists in a Set, `set.include?(o)` results in one extra operation compared to looking directly at a Hash, `hash[o]`, since that's what `include?` does internally. In that case I use a hash. If I want to do Set operations beyond a lookup/test for inclusion of a single element then I use Set. @sawa might have other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I would start using the gem: phrasie
This gives you a array of words in (each) document,
which you can easily match with your keywords.

have a look: https://github.com/ashleyw/phrasie