# How to replace words inside template placeholders

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to replace `<%= Name %>` with "Some Person".

I'm using a regex because I want to modify it so that I don't have to worry about the spaces between `=` and `Name` as well as the `E` in `Name` and the `%>`

I tried:

```
body = %q(
  Hello <%= Name %>,
  This is a test. hello test
  some more stuff here 
  and here.

  <%= Name %>
)

parsed_body = body.gsub(/\A<%= Name %>\Z/, "Some person")
puts parsed_body
```

When `parsed_body` is printed out, the string is unchanged. What is wrong with my regex?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when you can do `require "erb"`?

Comment: This sounds like an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968)". Using regex isn't the right way to process templates. If you need to modify them, consider having multiple, smaller, templates ("partials") that you conditionally include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Regex, you have added the `\A` and `\z` anchors. These ensure that your regex only matches, if the string only contains exactly `<%= Name %>` with nothing before or after.

To match the your pattern anywhere in the string, you can simply remove the anchors:

```
parsed_body = body.gsub(/<%= Name %>/, "Some person")
```

Comment: That said, the syntax you used there looks like an ERB template. Instead of using a regex, you might be much better of when using ERB to render your string.

Comment: The problem with this approach is a separate `gsub` has to be written for every possible target and substitution. That results in a lot of repeated code which then violates the DRY principle.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to write your own template parser, which is asking for a lot more trouble that it's worth considering those already exist.

However, this is the basic idea for such a thing:

```
erb = <<EOT
Owner: <%= name %>
Location: <%= address %>
EOT

FIELD_DATA = {
  name: 'Olive Oyl',
  address: '5 Sweethaven Village'
}

FIELD_RE = Regexp.union(FIELD_DATA.keys.map(&:to_s)).source # => "name|address"

puts erb.gsub(/<%=\s+(#{FIELD_RE})\s+%>/) { |k|
  k # => "<%= name %>", "<%= address %>"
  k[/\s+(\S+)\s+/, 1]  # => "name",        "address"
  FIELD_DATA[k[/\s+(\S+)\s+/, 1].to_sym]  # => "Olive Oyl",   "5 Sweethaven Village"
}
```

Which, when run, outputs:

```
Owner: Olive Oyl
Location: 5 Sweethaven Village
```

This works because `gsub` can take a regular expression and a block. For every match of the expression it passes in the match to the block, which is then used to return the actual value being substituted in.

If you have a lot of target values, rather than use `Regexp.union`, instead use the [RegexpTrie](https://github.com/gfx/ruby-regexp_trie) gem. See "[Is there an efficient way to perform hundreds of text substitutions in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395236/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-perform-hundreds-of-text-substitutions-in-ruby/5395777#5395777)" for more information.

Again, template parsers exist, they've been around a long time, they're very well tested, and they handle edge cases you haven't thought about, so don't write a new partially-implemented one, instead reuse an existing one.

Comment: Hahaha I had the same thought

Comment: It's the right solution once someone knows how `gsub` works.

Comment: Agreed although it can be done more dynamically without the need to string slice inside the gsub block

Answer (score 1):

Just another option considering what I am assuming you are trying to accomplish

```
tag_pattern = /(?<open_tag><%=\s*)(?<key>(\w+))(?<close_tag>\s*%>)/
body = <<-B
   Hello, 
    My name is <%= Name %> and I know some things. Just because I am a 
    <%= Occupation %> doesn't mean I know everything, but I sure can 
    <%=Duty%> just as well as anyone else.
    Also please don't replace <%= This %>

  Thank you,
    <%= Name %>
B
dict = {"Name" => "engineersmnky", "Occupation" => "Monkey", "Duty" => "drive a train"} 

 body.gsub(tag_pattern) {|m| dict[$2] || m }
 #=>  Hello, 
 #   My name is engineersmnky and I know some things. Just because I am a 
 #   Monkey doesn't mean I know everything, but I sure can 
 #   drive a train just as well as anyone else.
 #   Also please don't replace <%= This %>
 #
 # Thank you,
 #   engineersmnky
```

In this case I used a dictionary of the anticipated portions of the "erb" to be replaced and used the block style of `String#gsub` to handle the replacements where `$2` is the named capture `key`. When there is not a matching key it just leaves the match untouched e.g. `"Also please don't replace <%= This %>"`

You could implement this with any pattern you choose but if you are going to use "erb" style lines maybe try leveraging `erb` other wise the same will work below:

```
tag_pattern = (?<open_tag>{!!\s*)(?<key>(\w+))(?<close_tag>\s*!\?})
body = <<-B Hello, 
     My name is {!! Name !?} and I know some things. Just because I am a 
     {!! Occupation !?} doesn't mean I know everything, but I sure can 
     {!!Duty !?} just as well as anyone else.

    Thank you,
       {!! Name !?}
B
```

As long as you define `tag_pattern` correctly the replacement is fairly simple. [Rubular Example](http://rubular.com/r/VCThNjoTbt)